# Telegraf parsing logstash-style "grok" patterns

Tags: regex, logstash, influxdb, logstash-grok, telegraf

I have been trying to ingest data into influx from a log file. The structure is as follows

```
20171130-22:02:21.832 : something data work now
20171230-22:02:22.843 : something data2
20171231-22:02:23.232 : something data3
```

I have used this pattern

```
[inputs.logparser.grok]
        #patterns = ['%{ts-"20060102-15:04:05.999":timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA:random_data}']
        patterns = ['(?<timestamp>\d{8}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)\s*:\s*%{GREEDYDATA:random_data}']
```

Can I get help regarding formulating the pattern ?

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
(?<timestamp>\d{8}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)\s*:\s*%{GREEDYDATA:random_data}
```

**Details**

- `(?<timestamp>\d{8}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)` - `timestamp` field pattern:

  - `\d{8}` - 9 digits
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` - 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:` and 2 digits
  - `\.\d+` - a dot and 1+ digits
- `\s*:\s*` - `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespace chars
- `%{GREEDYDATA:random_data}` - a `.*`, anything up to the end of the line

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It says Error parsing log line: error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?<` ... Can you help me with the syntax in order to write to influx successfully ? I am very new at this ..

Comment: Sorry, are you sure you are using the regex with Grok? Because Grok regex flavor supports named capturing groups, they are used for setting extracted field names.

Comment: I think yes. Here is the syntax that I am using [inputs.logparser.grok]
        #patterns = ['%{ts-"20060102-15:04:05.999":timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA:random_data}']
        patterns = ['(?<timestamp>\d{8}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)\s*:\s*%{GREEDYDATA:random_data}']

Comment: @phaigeim Please check [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html). I am sure there is some problem with how the pattern is used. I tested it at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and it works well.

Comment: Thanks again @Wiktor. I have been using this https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/logparser in order to construct the patterns. Somethings didn't work with telegraf while they worked at grokdebug.herokuapp.com .. Is it different ?

Comment: The document says -- The Telegraf grok parser uses a slightly modified version of logstash "grok" patterns, with the format

%{<capture_syntax>[:<semantic_name>][:<modifier>]}

Comment: Try with `custom_patterns`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160426/discussion-between-phaigeim-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Did you solve the problem? in that case can you post how?

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu Doesn't the above work? See https://regex101.com/r/4dDCcd/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have a slighly different problem, I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655530/telegraf-tail-with-grok-pattern-error